# XMPP Library with Jingle in Objective C for iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, xmpp

Is there one?  Smack from Ignite Realtime / Jive seems to be a good fit, but it's Java based.  There's xmppframework but I don't believe it has support for Jingle.  Would it be possible to either compile the Smack Java library for use in iPhone development?  Alternatively, what would be the approach to extending xmppframework to include support for Jingle?

Comment: did u get anything related to Jingle and Objective C?

Answer (score 1):

The xmpp.org site has a list of libraries for jabber.  I suspect that most of the C or C++ ones should be buildable as a iOS library.

see:  http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you: https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/ ?

"libjingle is a collection of open-source C++ code and sample applications that enables you to build a peer-to-peer application. The code handles creating a network connection (through NAT and firewall devices, relay servers, and proxies), negotiating session details (codecs, formats, etc.), and exchanging data. It also provides helper tasks such as parsing XML, and handling network proxies."

Comment: I believe the questioner was looking for Objective C, not C++.